# laravel public_html files fail to load in shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

My laravel (v5.8) project works fine in localhost , but after I uploaded it to `cPanel` all images and css and JS files in public html failed to load in the browser and show errors in browser console like :

> "Failed to load our-approach.png:1 resource: the server responded with
> a status of 404 ()" 
>  "Failed to load resource: the main.css:1
> server responded with a status of 500 ()"

While the framework itself loaded fine and show no errors.
I updated PHP to `7.4` and followed almost every youtube and StackOverflow thread and nothing worked.

***index.php modified :***

```
  require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';

  $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

***AppServiceProvider.php modified***

```
public function register()
{

  $this -> app -> bind('path.public', function()
    {
    return base_path('public_html');
    });

}
```

**My project structure in cPanel :**

|-- bin
|-- cache
|-- **laravel** *(project files without the public folder)* 
         |-- app 
         |-- bootstrap
         |-- config
         .env  
         server.php  
         ... and the rest of the files
|-- etc
|-- logs
|-- mail
|-- **public_html**
         |-- css
         |-- js
         |-- img
         .htaccess
         index.php
         ...rest of files

**My htaccess file in public_html :**

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
  </IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: can you post your .htaccess file?

Comment: @alex hey Alex i added htaccess files to the question

Comment: May be, your static files not loaded for wrong path. Do you check the path of your content?

Comment: @STA In browser console it shows the path correct https://www.mywebsitename.com/img/image.png and the image already exist but still shows 404 error when i click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was in the files permission , i set it to 755 for folders and 644 for files and everything worked like charm

Answer (score 1):

You need changes in .htaccess file.

Add these lines

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But please take a backup before doing changes in htaccess files

Comment: I added these lines then the site didn't load totally , '' site can't be reached'' in browser

Comment: @ivan there are two .htaccess files, add them in the root folder one

Comment: I did the change but same exact issue , only css and js link that are called with CDN worked but files in public_html none loaded